# will QTP be able to exit the current test script and run the next test script (through the master driver script) in case of multi-tier architecture?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Below is the design of our 3 tier QTP framework. My question is

1. will QTP be able to exit the current test script and run the next test script (through the master driver script) if an error occurs in Tier2 or Tier3?
2. Is the there any problem with code for the master script which i have written below. The master scripts executes the individual test script and writes the result status, start time and end time into a dictionary which in turn is written back to an excel sheet
3. Do you guys see any other limitation/improvement of this design?
   Please Help!

```html
Master Driver Script – Tier1

Function Master ()
 ‘Take the contents of the excel sheet which stores the path of the test scrip        to be executed, status, start time and end time in a record set
     Do While Not oRecSet.EOF
   dicResultSet.Add rCnt, CreateObject (“Scripting.Dictionary”)
   For Each oField In oRecSet.Fields
    dicResultSet (rCnt).Add oField.Name, oField.Value
    ‘Execute individual scripts
    If oField.Name = “Path” Then
     msQTPapp.Open oField.Value, True
                                        Set qtTestScript = msQTPapp.Test
                                        qtTestScript.Settings.Run.OnError = "NextStep"
                                        strStartTime = Now
                                        qtTestScript.Run
                                        qtTestScript.Close
                                        strEndTime = Now
    End If
    ‘Write the status of the last run script in the dictionary object
    If oField.Name = “Status” Then
                    dicResultSet (rCnt).Item (“Status”)=_                 qtTestScript.LastRunResults.Status
    End If
    ‘Write the start time of the last run script in the dictionary     object
    If oField.Name = “StartTime” Then
                    icResultSet (rCnt).Item (“StartTime”) = strStartTime
    End If
    ‘Write the end time of the last run script in the dictionary object
    If oField.Name = “EndTime” Then
                    dicResultSet (rCnt).Item (“EndTime”) = strEndTime
                    qtTestScript = Nothing
    End If
   Next
   oRecSet.MoveNext
   rCnt= rCnt+1
  Loop
        'Write the status, start time and end time of the individual test scripts in an excel sheet 
        'Close the rec set and connection
End Function 

Test Script: Action – Tier2

‘Associate the individual test script with Environmental files, OR and other function library
Function Test1 ()
 ‘Call L1 from Function lib
 ‘Call L2 from Function lib
End Function

Function Library– Tier3

Function L1()
 ‘Actual task is getting done here
End Function
.
.
Function Ln()
 ‘Actual task is getting done here
End Function
```

Comment: How can we know while there is zero code, and zero description of what you mean with "tier", and zero description of how your "master" script calls the other scripts, in the question?

Comment: With 'Tier' I meant level i.e. the flow is from Tier1 (master sctipt) to Tier2 (Test Scripts) to (Function library). The master scripts will fetch the path of the scripts from the excel sheet (Test Suite.xls) by using Excel as a database and it will stored in a dictionary. The MDS will execute the tests scripts one by one using the AOM.  
Start and end time of the individual scripts will be stored in a dictionary and at the end of MDS the same will be written in the Test suite.xls sheet.

Comment: We haven't written the complete code till now, we are still thinking about the design before the actual code. So just thought to cross check if we are going in the right direction or not?

Comment: Btw I don´t see the "framework" in your code. You are just having a "main" test that calls other tests, and you create a kind of convention for placing code into libraries. The "Actual task is getting done here" comment is misleading because: You execute the tests using .Run, hence there will be code in those test´s main action(s), but we don't see that here, so I don't see what makes this a "framework".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll focus on question 1. If you want to ask the other questions, please ask two separate questions. I fear, however, they will be closed due to being too broad, or being primarily opinion-based.

Short answer: **Yes**.

The test called via AOM could exit for example using `ExitTest`, and **the caller indeed could continue to execute another test**. This is exactly the same process as with tests that don't exit explicitely, but just execute their normal flow of execution, and then terminate gracefully.

Even if a test is aborted due to a runtime error, the caller script would regain control, and could continue just like after a successful test run.